# Dynamic properties in Realm

Tags: ios, swift2, realm

I am starting to work with Realm on iOS 8 or greater and looking at the documentation in Realm. I noticed that all of the properties have the `dynamic` keyword in front of them. Is that required in Realm?  I have read the Apple documentation on the keyword which can be found here. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, it is mandatory for normal `var` properties. From the [*realm docs*](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#property-attributes).

> Realm model properties need the `dynamic var` attribute in order for these properties to become accessors for the underlying database data.
>
> There are two exceptions to this: `List` and `RealmOptional` properties cannot be declared as dynamic because generic properties cannot be represented in the Objective-C runtime, which is used for dynamic dispatch of dynamic properties, and should always be declared with `let`.

The *dynamic* keyword is what allows for Realm to be notified of changes to model variables, and consequently reflect them to the database.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3, we declared our property like this

```
dynamic var Name : String = ""
```

In Swift 4, we declared our property like this

```
@objc dynamic var Name : String = ""
```